# How can I get the grpc gateway rest request response in protobuf?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-gateway

I am using gRPC gateway for the backward compatibility support but I encountered an issue where in our REST APIs we are using the Protobuf with REST. But in gRPC gateway we are using JSON as a response type.
Now when we have migrated towards gRPC, but I am not seeing any option where I will receive the response as a proto type not the JSON type. Can someone please help me in this?

I am getting `content-type` with the REST url: `application/json`
What I need: `application/x-protobuf`

EDIT:
I have this service contract

```
service TestService {
  rpc GetBattleStatusByEntityIds(ProtoRequest) returns (ProtoResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get : "/test"
    };
  }
}
```

When I am hitting this `/test` url then I am receiving the response with content type `application/json` but I need the data in `application/x-protobuf` format. I checked the grpc-gateway code and it is using a marshaller which change the response from protobuf to json. Can you please help me to keep it like json any code sample would help.

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/main/runtime/marshal_jsonpb.go

Picture of wanted response type: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvR3w.png

Comment: [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hey, updated the question. Please revisit.

Comment: I've **not** tried this. Envoy documents [sending arbitrary content](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter#sending-arbitrary-content) using Google's (!) [`google.api.HttpBody`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/httpbody.proto). I **assume** that this mechanism is supported by gRPC Gateway too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header - which grpc-gateway will then use when deciding how to render the response.

In the most simple sense, `Content-Type` indicates to the server what type of content the request body is, whilst `Accept` tells the server what type of content you're willing to accept in the response body.

So in your case, you'll want to use `Accept: application/x-protobuf`

```
$ curl -s -X POST --header 'Accept: application/x-protobuf' localhost:8081/test | hexdump -C
00000000  0a 04 08 0a 10 03                                 |......|
```

Continue to set the `Content-Type` header if you're sending content too.

Comment: It's not working in grpc-gateway, content-type is still application/json

Comment: You need to share some code then, as it works perfectly well for me. This is how I've set it up on my side: https://gist.github.com/nick-jones/f404ae94b38d4c701f8d539cac5c1ae0

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer while initialising the NewServeMux, I need to add my custom marshaler. Gateway have already proto marshaler which saves my efforts.

```golang
gatewayMux := runtime.NewServeMux(
        runtime.WithMarshalerOption("application/protobuf", &runtime.ProtoMarshaller{}),
    )
```